# How to make version compatible of a pdf file through itextsharp in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, download, itext

I want to create a downlodable pdf file through itextsharp dll (ver 5.0.5). I have four textboxes which is filled by the user and click on download pdf file. Filled text paste in specific location in existing pdf file and make it downloadable. User can open or save that file. My code to create a file is:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";                                                                                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Patient Refund Request " + txtPatientName.Text + ".pdf");

string sourceFile = Server.MapPath("~/Forms/Refund.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);    
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
Document document = new Document(size);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
document.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(0, txtDate.Text, 260, 655, 0);
cb.EndText();

cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(0, txtPatientName.Text, 260, 620, 0);
cb.EndText();

cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(0, txtPatDOB.Text, 260, 588, 0);
cb.EndText();

cb.BeginText();
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(new Chunk(txtDescription.Text, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD))), 90, 440, 550, 36, 20, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
ct.Go();
cb.EndText();

PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

document.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

This code is working fine and open the pdf file and show all contents. 
My issue is, this pdf is only open in adobe reader 9 or greater version. It is not opening in lower version such as adobe reader 6 or 7. I have opened it in adobe acrobat 7.0. but it could not be open. All users in my company have adobe acrobat 6 or 7.
 How can I make this code version compatible that this downloadable file can open by every version minimum version 6. I hope this information is sufficient for your knowledge. Kindly give sum suggestion or code. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default version for iText and iTextSharp is `PDF 1.4` which should be compatible with Adobe Acrobat 5 and greater so I'm not sure why you are having a problem with 6 and 7. But if you want to change the version you can do it this way:

```
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_2;
```

I would recommend setting this immediately after creating the `writer` object.

Comment: Thanks Chris for reply. I used this code in my application. Now it is opening the file. But a problem has come. When I save this pdf file in any static location e.g. "C:\\" drive. It opened easily but when I create it dynamically and make it downloadable without saving any location(specified before) it gives an error **"There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."** I need only downloadable file which ask by the user where he want to save this file. What should I do?

Comment: My guess is that you have some extra junk in the HTTP stream. Make sure you call `Response.End` or something similar to close the stream.

Comment: Yes chris you are right. I forgot to put the response.End() at the end of the code. Now my code is working file and able to download the file. Many Many thanks to you. Thanks for the help.